# Что делать с веткой после выкатки pull request?

Tags: git

Вот сделал я форк нужного мне репозитория, склонировал свой репо на локальную машину. Создал branch, добавил в него файлы, выкатил на remote, отправил pull-request. А branch остался. Что мне с ним делать? Нужно ли его удалять? И что будет, если у меня таких веток будет 500 штук?

Comment: Если запрос слили с основной веткой, то смысла в дополнительной практически мало. Количество веток не так сильно влияет, как отличие содержимого в них от основных. Тогда репозиторий раздувается сильно.